# csv reader finds less rows than bufio scanner

Tags: csv, go

I downloaded the IMDb dataset title.basics.tsv.gz and a `wc -l data.tsv` results in 7434601 rows.

Now I'm trying to read the data in Go, but csv.Reader only reads 5901463 rows. When I use bufio.Scanner it's the same number of rows that wc spits out though.

There are no fancy settings and no comment rune is configured: Tab as comma, reuse records (same result without resuing records BTW) and lazy quotes because some IMDb titles require that.

```golang
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "unicode/utf8"
)

func main() {
    f, err := os.Open(`C:\path\to\data.tsv`)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Couldn't open TSV file: %v\n", err)
    }

    r := csv.NewReader(f)
    r.Comma, _ = utf8.DecodeRuneInString("\t")
    r.ReuseRecord = true
    r.LazyQuotes = true

    i := 0
    for ; ; i++ {
        _, err := r.Read()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("CSV read error: %v\n", err)
            break
        }
    }
    fmt.Printf("CSV reader count: %v\n", i) // 5901463

    _, err = f.Seek(0, 0)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Couldn't reset file reader: %v\n", err)
    }
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(f)
    i = 0
    for ; ; i++ {
        if !scanner.Scan() {
            break
        }
    }
    fmt.Printf("Scanner count: %v\n", i) // 7434601
}
```

The 7434601 rows seem to be fine - whith the bufio Scanner I used `strings.Split` by tab on `scanner.Text()` to see if each row has 9 elements, which was the case.

Comment: Some of the fields in the document contain a newline.  The code `r.Comma, _ = utf8.DecodeRuneInString("\t")` can be simplified to `r.Comma = '\t'`.

Comment: But as written at the end of the question, strings.Split on tab on each scanned row leads to 9 elements each.

Comment: Looks like you are reporting a bug. Do you have an actual question?

Comment: I'm a Go novice, I can't imagine I found a bug in the standard library. There must be something I'm overlooking and I'm asking for help what that is 

Comment: Fields values containing `"` cause the problem.  Beyond that, I don't understand what's going on.

Comment: Indeed you're right! The bufio scanner is correct, but the csv reader (due to lazy quotes) and a title like `"foo" bar` reads _beyond_ the first tab until in some later row there's another quote I think. I don't see a way to configure the csv reader to completely ignore quotes. With lazy quotes off it leads to an error with that title.

I think that answers the question! Do you want to write an answer, then I'll mark it as solution.

Comment: Look at the other question. You may need to "preprocess" the tsv file and escape all quotes or use a different, smarter, parser.

Comment: Use bufio.Scanner to read records and strings.Split the records on `\t` to get the fields. The encoding/csv package does much more than what you need.